# Replace all spaces within square brackets with underscore using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all spaces within square brackets to underscore.
I was wondering how to do it.
I tried:     s.replaceAll("\[(\s*)\]","_");
but it doesn't replace the spaces.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: `.replaceAll("\\s(?=[^\\[\\]]*])","_");`

Comment: `String replaced = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]").matcher("a b [c d e] f g").replaceAll(match -> match.group().replace(' ', '_'));`

Comment: Or, `replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|\\[(?=[^\\]\\[]*]))([^\\]\\[\\s]*)\\s", "$1$2_")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWRcQM/2)).

Comment: thank you all. you really helped. the links they specified as similar aren't similar at all. what makes them think it is relevant?